# Drawing rectangles on chart C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I want to draw some rectangles on a chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart). I've tried looking at some tutorials, althought most of them are about drawing on a form and not on a chart.

Here is some code I've made based on some tutorials. It does not work, the chart simply goes blank.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private RectangleF r1;
    private RectangleF r2;

    public Form1()
    {
        r1.X = 10;
        r1.Y = 10;
        r1.Width = 20;
        r1.Height = 20.5F;

        r1.X = 100;
        r1.Y = 100;
        r1.Width = 200;
        r1.Height = 300;

        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.chart1.PostPaint += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs>(this.PostPaint);
    }

    private void PostPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(r1);

    }
}
```

In this example I've created as well, only the second rectangle is drawn and the chart shows no axis at all. I want to draw multiples triangles using floats.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Rectangle r1;
    private Rectangle r2;

    public Form1()
    {
        r1.X = 10;
        r1.Y = 10;
        r1.Width = 20;
        r1.Height = 20;

        r1.X = 100;
        r1.Y = 100;
        r1.Width = 200;
        r1.Height = 300;

        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.chart1.PostPaint += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs>(this.PostPaint);
    }

    private void PostPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {

        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), r1);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 5), r2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding the chart to form? It looks like you hook up event for different chart.

Comment: I don't think I am. I have a form with a chart (chart1) in it. I have Null Pointer Exceptions when testing and I solved them by adding System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart().

Comment: Completely get rid of that line `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();`, If you haved named chart1 in designer that should work

Comment: Removed and works fine now, without any null pointer exception.

Comment: So your all problems resolved?

Comment: Sort of, it now draws multiples rectangles like I wanted, but I need to  search more about the axes.

Answer (score 1):

In both examples, you're setting the values for `r1` twice instead of `r1` and `r2`.

In your first example, [`GetAbsoluteRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartgraphics.getabsoluterectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not draw a rectangle. It is used for converting coordinates. You should use `DrawRectangle` like you are in the second example.

Comment: If that's the only problem atleast one rectangle should be drawn isn't it? Problem is even bigger, refer my first comment.

Comment: Updated. In your first example you're not using the right method.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've already changed r1 to r2 but I have some questions:
 In the first example, DrawRectangle won't let me draw because it requires rectangles with X, Y, height and width as int. How can I draw when using floats?
 In the second example, it now draws the two rectangles but how can I make the axis visible?

Comment: The `Rectangle` class only supports `int`s because it maps to pixels. You can't draw on half a pixel.

Comment: Also I'm not sure but it looks like you have to add the axes manually. The documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So basically whenever I want to draw a rectangle, it must always be Rectangle.
I'll look further about the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
r1.X = 100;
r1.Y = 100;
r1.Width = 200;
r1.Height = 300;
```

By that :

```
r2.X = 100;
r2.Y = 100;
r2.Width = 200;
r2.Height = 300;
```

It will - normaly - works fine.

Comment: Thank you, it now draws the two rectangles.