# C# Draw Circle on top of control

Tags: c#

I have a chart with a point (those quadcopter images) and I want to draw a circle on that point with x radius. I cant figure out how to do it.

I want this [image]

Code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < drone.Length; i++)
        {

            var pos_atual = drone[i].posicao_atual;
            var pos_desej = drone[i].posicao_desejada;
                chart.Series[i].Points.Clear();

                chart.Series[i].Points.AddXY(drone[i].pos_atual().X, drone[i].pos_atual().Y);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Why people dislike my post... What's wrong with it?

Comment: Provide more context to begin with.

Comment: I just want to draw a circle with a radius with a center point `drone[i].pos_atual().X, drone[i].pos_atual().Y)` in chart location.

Comment: What's so hard to understand?

Comment: For starters, what is the type of variable `chart`?

Comment: See [Drawing rectangles on chart C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23683972/719186)

Comment: Well, folks often downvote when they see a lack of research..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code one of the xxxPaint events, maybe like this:

```
private void chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Series s = chart.Series[yourSeriesIndex];

    int yourPointIndex = 4;

    if (s.Points.Count < yourPointIndex) return;

    DataPoint dp = s.Points[yourPointIndex];
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

    int x = (int) ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
    int y = (int) ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
    // a  circle with 20 pixels diameter
    e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, x-10, y-10, 20, 20);

}
```

[image]

As an alternative you can add a `Marker` with `MarkerStyle Circle`, `Color Transparent` and `MarkerBorderColor Red` to the `DataPoint`..:

```
Chart chart = TestChart;
Series s = chart.Series[0];

DataPoint dp = s.Points[5];

dp.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
dp.MarkerSize = 20;  // diameter in pixels 
dp.MarkerColor = Color.Transparent;
dp.MarkerBorderColor = Color.Orange;
dp.MarkerBorderWidth = 2;
```

**Update**

From you comment I understand that you want is to set the size of the circle not in  **pixels** but in data point **values**.

This is also possible and not really hard; however it does take some understanding of the `Chart` rules.

Here we go:

First we define the width and height we want. Note how my numbers are quite different from yours and how they are also not the same for width and height!!

```
double vx = 1d;
double vy = 20d;
```

Next we calculate the sizes; they are the difference (!) between zero and our values. This seems complicated, but look at my chart: The y-axis starts in the **negative**. So simply getting the pixels from one value will be quite offset..

```
int wx = (int) ( ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(vx) -  
                 ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(0)) ;
int wy = (int) ( ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(vy) -  
                 ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(0)) ;
```

With these numbers we can draw the circle:

```
e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, x - wx / 2, y - wy / 2, wx, wy);
```

Note how we start the **bounding rectangle** of the circle **offset** left and top by **half** the size!

Now the size will follow the chart size:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to call PostPaint or it's called by itself?

Comment: It gets called by itself; but if you want to use dynamic data in it, like a different Color or a different point index every second you need to call it with a `chart.Invalidate();`

Comment: What's this ` int yourPointIndex = 4;`

Comment: You want to draw red circle around a DataPoint, right? This is the index of that Point. The ring is drawn around the 5th point (4=5th in c#) - Do note the update with an alternative, which is nice for a simple ring, but less so for any more complex drawings.. Here I add an ornage marker around the 6th (#5) points

Comment: It's drawing outside x,y https://i.gyazo.com/f4402dba6102fc3eb21114b00133bdb0.png

Comment: I only needed this:   `e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, drone[i].pos_atual().X, drone[i].pos_atual().Y, 20, 20);`

Comment: I also wanted instead of 20 I wanted 20 related to the x,y size. not the actual chart size.

Comment: i fixed that. It's drawing outside the center of the point https://gyazo.com/b4cda345c52c7b381680169c811652ae

Comment: The 20 are 20 pixels in both cases. Not sure what you want instead; can explain?

Comment: Do you see the x axis for example? I wanted a circle with 20 radius not 20 pixels. Also do you know why the circle is not on the center of the point?

Comment: Taw please help me out.